# Nodejs: firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token) generate "Object has no method 'signInWithCustomToken'" error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

With new firebase version, y need to access by node.js at my firebase application.

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var parms={.......}
firebase.initializeApp(parms);
var token = firebase.auth().createCustomToken('123'); //Token generated successfully
//Line below throws error
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
      //do something
});
```

If I use signInWithCustomToken from javascript in the browser, it works fine. But if I use it from command line: *node file.js*, it throws the error: ***firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token) generate "Object has no method 'signInWithCustomToken'" error***

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this part the web and node apis are different.

As stated in the Upgrade Guide (https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#update_your_authentication_code_numbered)
 you need to use a service account for node.js apps. A good point to start is this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#section-account

I would have loved to paste you the links to the auth api pages, but I'm only allowed to post 2 links. :)